# How can I calculate F1-measure and ROC in multiclass classification problem in R?

Tags: r, classification, roc, multiclass-classification

I have this code for a multiclass classification problem:

```
data$Class = as.factor(data$Class)
levels(data$Class) <- make.names(levels(factor(data$Class)))
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(data$Class, p = 0.6, list = FALSE, times=1)
trainingSet <- data[ trainIndex,]
testingSet  <- data[-trainIndex,]
train_x <- trainingSet[, -ncol(trainingSet)]
train_y <- trainingSet$Class

testing_x <- testingSet[, -ncol(testingSet)]
testing_y <- testingSet$Class

oneRM <- OneR(trainingSet, verbose = TRUE)
oneRM
summary(oneRM)
plot(oneRM)    

oneRM_pred <- predict(oneRM, testing_x)
oneRM_pred

eval_model(oneRM_pred, testing_y)


AUC_oneRM_pred <- auc(roc(oneRM_pred,testing_y))
cat ("AUC=", oneRM_pred)

# Recall-Precision curve    
oneRM_prediction <- prediction(oneRM_pred, testing_y)
RP.perf <- performance(oneRM_prediction, "tpr", "fpr")

plot (RP.perf)

plot(roc(oneRM_pred,testing_y))
```

But code does not work, after this line:

> oneRM_prediction <- prediction(oneRM_pred, testing_y)

I get this error:

> Error in prediction(oneRM_pred, testing_y) : Format of predictions is
>   invalid.

In addition, I don´t know how I can get easily the F1-measure.

Finally, a question, does it make sense to calculate AUC in a multi-class classification problem?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from F1.

Assuming that you are using the iris dataset, first, we need to load everything, train the model and perform the predictions as you did.

```
library(datasets)
library(caret)
library(OneR)
library(pROC)

trainIndex <- createDataPartition(iris$Species, p = 0.6, list = FALSE, times=1)
trainingSet <- iris[ trainIndex,]
testingSet  <- iris[-trainIndex,]
train_x <- trainingSet[, -ncol(trainingSet)]
train_y <- trainingSet$Species

testing_x <- testingSet[, -ncol(testingSet)]
testing_y <- testingSet$Species

oneRM <- OneR(trainingSet, verbose = TRUE)
oneRM_pred <- predict(oneRM, testing_x)
```

Then, you should calculate the precision, recall, and F1 for each class.

```
cm <- as.matrix(confusionMatrix(oneRM_pred, testing_y))
n = sum(cm) # number of instances
nc = nrow(cm) # number of classes
rowsums = apply(cm, 1, sum) # number of instances per class
colsums = apply(cm, 2, sum) # number of predictions per class
diag = diag(cm)  # number of correctly classified instances per class 

precision = diag / colsums 
recall = diag / rowsums 
f1 = 2 * precision * recall / (precision + recall) 

print(" ************ Confusion Matrix ************")
print(cm)
print(" ************ Diag ************")
print(diag)
print(" ************ Precision/Recall/F1 ************")
print(data.frame(precision, recall, f1))
```

After that, you are able to find the macro F1.

```
macroPrecision = mean(precision)
macroRecall = mean(recall)
macroF1 = mean(f1)

print(" ************ Macro Precision/Recall/F1 ************")
print(data.frame(macroPrecision, macroRecall, macroF1))
```

To find the ROC (precisely the AUC), it best to use `pROC` library.

```
print(" ************ AUC ************")
roc.multi <- multiclass.roc(testing_y, as.numeric(oneRM_pred))
print(auc(roc.multi))
```

Hope that it helps you.

Find details on this [link](https://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2016/03/com_class_eval_metrics_r.html) for F1 and [this](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pROC/versions/1.14.0/topics/multiclass.roc) for AUC.

Comment: In my dataset, after: cm <- as.matrix(confusionMatrix(oneRM_pred, testing_y))
I get this error: Error in confusionMatrix.default(oneRM_pred, testing_y) : The data contain levels not found in the data.

Comment: Take a look at: https://arulvelkumar.wordpress.com/2017/07/06/confusionmatrix-function-in-r-the-data-contain-levels-not-found-in-the-data/

Answer (score 0):

If I use **levels(oneRM_pred) <- levels(testing_y)** in this way:

```
...
oneRM <- OneR(trainingSet, verbose = TRUE)
oneRM
summary(oneRM)
plot(oneRM)    

oneRM_pred <- predict(oneRM, testing_x)
levels(oneRM_pred) <- levels(testing_y)
...
```

The accuracy is very much lower than before. So, I am not sure if to enforce the same levels is a good solution.